# Apply non-linear regression for multi dimension data samples in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have installed Numpy and SciPy, but I'm not quite understand their documentation about `polyfit`.

For exmpale, Here's my three data samples:

```
[-0.042780748663101636, -0.0040771571786609945, -0.00506567946276074]
[0.042780748663101636, -0.0044771571786609945, -0.10506567946276074]
[0.542780748663101636, -0.005771571786609945, 0.30506567946276074]
[-0.342780748663101636, -0.0304077157178660995, 0.90506567946276074]
```

The first two columns are sample features, the third column is output, My target is to get a function that could take two parameters(first two columns) and return its prediction(the output).

Any simple example ?

> ====================== EDIT ======================

Note that, I need to fit something like a `curve`, not only straight lines. The polynomial should be something like this ( n = 3):

```
a*x1^3 + b*x2^2 + c*x3 + d = y
```

Not:

```
a*x1 + b*x2 + c*x3 + d = y
```

> **`x1`, `x2`, `x3` are features of one sample, `y` is the output**

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html

Comment: @WoooHaaaa I suggest using GEKKO package of Python to perform nonlinear multivariate regression analysis. An illustrative example of its application can be found here: https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/NonlinearRegression

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like

**edit**: added an example function that used results of linear regression to estimate output.

```
import numpy as np
data =np.array(
[[-0.042780748663101636, -0.0040771571786609945, -0.00506567946276074],
[0.042780748663101636, -0.0044771571786609945, -0.10506567946276074],
[0.542780748663101636, -0.005771571786609945, 0.30506567946276074],
[-0.342780748663101636, -0.0304077157178660995, 0.90506567946276074]])

coefficient = data[:,0:2]
dependent = data[:,-1]

x,residuals,rank,s = np.linalg.lstsq(coefficient,dependent)

def f(x,u,v):
    return u*x[0] + v*x[1]

for datum in data:
    print f(x,*datum[0:2])
```

Which gives

```
>>> x
array([  0.16991146, -30.18923739])
>>> residuals
array([ 0.07941146])
>>> rank
2
>>> s
array([ 0.64490113,  0.02944663])
```

and the function created with your coefficients gave

```
0.115817326583
0.142430900298
0.266464019171
0.859743371665
```

More info can be found at the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) I posted as a comment.

**edit 2:** fitting your data to an arbitrary model.

**edit 3:** made my model a function for ease of understanding.

**edit 4:** made code more easily read/ changed model to a quadratic fit, but you should be able to read this code and know how to make it minimize any residual you want now.

contrived example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

data =np.array(
[[-0.042780748663101636, -0.0040771571786609945, -0.00506567946276074],
[0.042780748663101636, -0.0044771571786609945, -0.10506567946276074],
[0.542780748663101636, -0.005771571786609945, 0.30506567946276074],
[-0.342780748663101636, -0.0304077157178660995, 0.90506567946276074]])

coefficient = data[:,0:2]
dependent = data[:,-1]

def model(p,x):
    a,b,c = p
    u = x[:,0]
    v = x[:,1]
    return (a*u**2 + b*v + c)

def residuals(p, y, x):
    a,b,c = p
    err = y - model(p,x)
    return err

p0 = np.array([2,3,4]) #some initial guess

p = leastsq(residuals, p0, args=(dependent, coefficient))[0]

def f(p,x):
    return p[0]*x[0] + p[1]*x[1] + p[2]

for x in coefficient:
    print f(p,x)
```

gives

```
-0.108798280153
-0.00470479385807
0.570237823475
0.413016072653
```

Comment: This `f(x, u, v)` will only fit straight lines, is it ? I need to fit a **curve**.

Comment: Okay, I'll add to my answer.

Comment: Okay, arbitrary model example added.  (you did explicitly mention linear regression in the question title, though)

Comment: Thanks @seth, I thought linear regression includes arbitrary lines, both straight line and curve line. isn't it ?

Comment: **linear** regression :-).  One variable is a line, two is a plane we are familiar with visualizing, and higher dimensions are also planes, but hyper planes.  an `N` dimensional linear regression will try to least squares `y=px`, i.e. `y = p1*x1 + p2*x2 + ... pn*xn` where p are parameters for the model, like `a,b,c,...` and `x1...xn` are the elements of your `N` dimensional input vector. `y` is your dependent vector. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

Comment: Hmm ... seems I had misunderstand it, I mean non-linear regression... :D

Comment: The code I've provided allows for you to assume whatever kind of model you like.  The model is defined explicitly in the `model` function, the `residuals` function is the difference between your `model` and the real value `y`.  We use `leastsq` to minimize that difference and obtain values for the parameters of the model we defined.

Comment: Thanks @seth ! It's very very helpful for me to understand it.